# Comparing column values and ignoring the order of element DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a column where I need to check whether the column value contains the same data in any order.

I want to get the first value as output value if the value matches in any order.

[image]

Can we do this using DAX ??

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with DAX to advise.  But you can do it in Power Query M Code.

Comment: if the number of elements has a known limit (so e.g. max 3 values) then I think it is technically possible. The performance would be terribly bad and the solution would be really clunky, but it's possible. With that said, you shouldn't do it in DAX, M/PowerQuery is much better suited for this kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case ever needed, this seem to work in M / Powerquery

It splits, sorts and recombines the Combo Code column, then merges on itself and picks up the first matching row

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Combo code", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(Text.Split([Combo code], ",")), ",")),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"},#"Added Custom",{"Custom"},"Added Custom",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Output", each Table.First([Added Custom])[Combo code]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom", "Added Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can get the correct output (not tested on large dataset);

```
IFMatch = 
VAR mymeasure =
    SUBSTITUTE (SELECTEDVALUE(MatchingTable[Combo code])
    , ",", "|" )
VAR Mylen =
    PATHLENGTH ( mymeasure )+1
VAR mytable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, Mylen ),
        "mylist",  ( PATHITEM ( mymeasure, [Value] ) )
    )
VAR mylist =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( mytable, "list", [mylist] )

// SecondColumnToTable
    VAR Outp =
    SUBSTITUTE ( SELECTEDVALUE(MatchingTable[Output]), ",", "|" )
VAR OutpMylen =
    PATHLENGTH ( Outp ) +1
VAR Outpmytable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, Outpmylen ),
        "mylist",  ( PATHITEM ( Outp, [Value] ) )
    )
VAR Outpmylist =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( Outpmytable, "list", [mylist] )
RETURN
    if(Mylen = OutpMylen && Mylen = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS (INTERSECT(mylist,Outpmylist) )),TOPN(1, Outpmylist), "N/D")
```

[image]